# Filezilla timeout after 20 seconds of inactivity

Tags: networking, router, ftp

After changing my dlink router with a Netgear d6000 I'm no longer able to connect to ftps via filezilla. The settings for ftp connections remained the same but after connecting to the server, Filezilla timeouts after 20 seconds of reading folders(nothing appears in the directory tree). Same problems with different ftps. I don't know if it's router related.

Edit: It's not a timeout issue. Changing the timeout value doesn't change the problem. It blocks when reading folders.

Comment: just a comment for others who may be desperate, I ran into this same problem with fileZilla and after trying every answer to this question, I begrudgingly finally tried cyberduck - and it just worked right away.

Answer (score 20):

In my case

1. Click Edit on Menu
2. Click Settings
3. Set Time Out to '0'

That's it. It worked in my case.
Tried all the above mentioned methods but it wont make any change in my problem.

By just disabling the time out it worked.

Answer (score 17):

1. Open Site manager
2. Click on “New site” button
3. You need to change the Encryption to “Only use plain FTP (insecure)” and Logon type to Normal
4. Enter host address, user name and password and click “Connect”
5. Proceed as per the messages, you may need to enter the passwords again , enter it.

**[Click here](https://www.geekiest.net/post/Filezilla-FTP-How-to-fix-connection-timed-out-error.aspx)** to see the details with screenshots

Comment: Flagged as not-an-answer, because having a problem with a secure connection, and saying "turn off the security" doesn't fix it. Besides, the server may not accept unsecure FTP connections.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler *Not an answer* should be used for things which are not answers (comments, "I'm having this problem too" etc); it's not a technical judgement of the merits of an answer. You are of course free (and encouraged!) to point out the merits of such an answer in the comments, and propose an alternative using the 'post an answer' button :)

Comment: @bertieb "My FTPS doesn't work", "don't use FTPS" really seems like not-an-answer to me, but .. ok if you say so. As soon as I have an alternative which actually is an answer, and I've fixed my own FTPS connection issue, which is how I got here at all, maybe I will post an answer. But it isn't Netgear related, so it likely won't apply.

Comment: (In addition to the generic advice above, there are cases where I might not worry so much about security, such as connections between two virtual machines on my home LAN; an answer which solves the issue of a timeout while compromising security might be helpful in such an instance, for example)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler it doesn't solve the underlying problem, agreed. It is a workaround, agreed. But frame challenges are acceptable (eg "How can I use the fill command on a photo in MS Paint" "Use a different tool that supports layers" was a recent example off the top of my head); so this is still an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Open FileZilla client application on your desktop. A new window will open for FileZilla.
2. Click Edit on menu bar and select Settings option.
3. Click Settings and a new small Settings window will open. In the left side of the Settings window there is a subsection  called Select page, select the top option called Connection (by default it is selected when you open Settings window if it is not then select it manually). When you click on the connection link you will get an option to set timeout on the right side. In that Timeout section you will get an option to set timeout value from 0-599 seconds. Set this according to your need or you can disable this Timeout settings by settings its value to 0.

Comment: These timeout settings in FileZilla server are not related to the timeout problems mentioned in the OT. By default, there is no 20 secs timeout configured in FileZilla, they are all set to 1 or 2 mins by default. Even if I set it to 0, I get the same "20 seconds inactivity" message, so it must be some other limit setting somewhere (I assume outside of FileZilla).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I switched from a D-Link router to a Asus RT-AC68U.

My problems where solved by disabling the NAT Acceleration.
This description is for a Asus router but look for NAT Acceleration/Hardware acceleration or something like that, if you have another router.

1. Login to the router
2. In the left menu, under Advanced Settings, click the LAN button.
3. Then click the Switch Control tab.
4. Set NAT Acceleration to Disable.

Comment: I get the mentioned error message of 20 seconds inactivity, but only for one certain remote FTP server, not for all. Therefore I assume it should not be related to the router, but to the remote server/network configuration.

Comment: I have the same issue ... if I connect by CLI the FTP looks working (`ls` retrieve directory )

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

> Advanced  -> NAT -> RIP CONFIG LIST -> Enable FTP

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Site manager
2. Click on “New site” button
3. You need to change the Encryption to “Only use plain FTP (insecure)”
   and Logon type to Normal
4. Enter host address(using ip is better
   ), user name and password and click “Connect”
5. Open transfer settings tab
6. Change transfer mode from `default` to `active`
7. Proceed as per the messages, you may need to enter the passwords
   again , enter it.

Comment: You don't fix a problem with a secure connection by turning of the security(!). And the server may not accept an insecure connection, and certainly 'active' FTP over the internet is very unlikely to work at all.

Comment: How is this substantively different from Ritabrata Gautam's answer?  Most of it is an identical copy.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but thought I would post my solution for others who come across this post.

1. Login to your Netgear D6000 router
2. Click on the Advanced tab
3. Click on Setup from the left hand menu
4. Click on WAN Setup
5. Tick the check box to Disable Port Scan and DoS Protection
6. Click on Apply

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had some commands in my `.bashrc` file which printed some general information (e.g. `gcc --version`) to the console whenever I logged in. These kind of outputs confused the FileZilla. I suppressed the commands and FileZilla worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but I solved it by using IP adress in the host field

Comment: @zx485: It lacks details, and I don’t see why it would be a correct answer, but it does appear to be ***an*** answer.

Comment: I was just pointing out the way I solved my problem. I am aware that it is not really an anwser. I would have put it in a comment, but as you can see, I don't have required reputaion for that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by setting up Port Mapping and Port Trigger on the Router Modem :

[Port Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBYOp.jpg) and [Port Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmvrn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its bcos of NAT ALG on my Skyworth Router. I disabled it and it fixed the issue instantly.
[image: filezilla inactivity failed to retreive directory listing]

It was enabled by default, I unchecked it. Now Filezilla is working perfect.
You guys might find some similar options, so this is working solution. Thanks to fwilhelmsson for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when changing to a new AX5400 Wi-Fi 6 Router. I setup the NAT port forwarding like I had with my previous router and made sure my FTP server nic had a static IP assigned that was the same as what I used in port forwarding settings (192.168.1.161) but it would not allow remote connections. I was finally able to get a successful connection when I went to "Advanced" tab, selected "network", and finally clicked on "Routing". From there I added a new route to my Static Routing table. I set the local IP of my FTP (192.168.1.161) server as the "Network Destination", Local network IP (255.255.255.0) as "Subnet Mask", my routers local IP (192.168.1.1) as "Default Gateway", set LAN as "Interface", and used FTP as my "Description". After adding this static routing I tested and was finally able to connect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).