# FileZilla Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity, Could not connect to server Cloudflare Issue

Tags: dns, ftp, filezilla, cpanel, cloudflare

Here is the connection log:

- Status:  Resolving address of ftp.mydomain.com
- Status:  Connecting to
  172.67.128.141:21...
- Error:   Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
- Error:   Could not connect to server
- Status:  Waiting to
  retry...
  The log is looping like this. retrying again and again.

I have tried some settings on the FileZilla site manager settings.

From this thread. [Filezilla timeout after 20 seconds of inactivity](https://superuser.com/questions/896206/filezilla-timeout-after-20-seconds-of-inactivity)
But could not connect to the server.
I have checked the A record for ftp.mydomain.com on Cloudflare it properly points to the server IP.

Since the server is a Cpanel WHM, I also created a support ticket.
 They told me to try the
FileZilla Site Manager with the Encryption option as `Only use Plain FTP(insecure)`
Did not work.

**What can be wrong with my Cloudflare DNS settings?**
Because when I use server IP as FTP Hostname I finally could connect to the server with FTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can use the server IP address as FTP hostname I simply changed the Proxy status of the A record from `proxied` to `DNS Only`. Now I can connect to FTP without any errors with the default FTP hostname which is `ftp.mydomain.com`
[Image of Proxy Status of the A record on Cloudflare DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkhd0.png)

Answer (score -1):

It works if you connect to a VPN then try it. I connected to a VPN server in Netherlands, and then the connection worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please add any details as to why this is the recommended solution and why Netherlands specifically.